# what is the best number of epochs before my model overfits?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Below is an image of a Neural Network model I'm running in Keras. You can see the MAE value against the # of Epochs. By looking at this plot I think the best number of Epochs is about 280 then the model overfits, am I right? I'm interested to hear your opinion!

I have a 500-sample dataset that I split 80/20 and used 4 fold. The model is set up like this:

```
 model = keras.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'), ##pay attention here. Added the "keras.layers"
      keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])
```

[image]

Comment: there's no theoretical best number. you should find it through trial and error. varies from model to model.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have fix number of epochs rather You can use keras callback ModelCheckpoint(which saves the best model during training) and EarlyStopping(which keep tracks of loss, acc, val_loss and val_acc stops training when model doesn't improve over epochs). So you don't need to find best number of epochs. You can give maximum number of epochs these callbacks will handle all e.g for how long model should train and the best model during training

read about callbacks [here](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/)